# Removed `rm` command in cygwin

Tags: package-management, rm, cygwin

Having the need to use a `bash` shell on a Windows computer (I'll spare you the details), I installed Cygwin, and a friend as a joke ran `rm /usr/bin/rm` on the terminal, and surprisingly nothing much happened other than `rm` being removed.

Is there any way to get back the `rm` program on Cygwin, or for that matter any distribution of Linux? As far as I know, there isn't any `rm` package on Red Hat or Debian systems I can reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm` is part of [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). So re-install that.

Cygwin doesn't have a fully-featured package manager, but you should be able to [rerun setup*.exe](http://cygwin.com/install.html) (i.e. the original installer - it remembers your packages) to re-select coreutils.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it definitely answers how to get back `rm` in a Linux distribution. However, is there any way to do so in Cygwin (which does not appear to have package management)?

Comment: That works, thank you! Also, `reinstall` needs to be selected for `coreutils`, or the installer will just say everything is already installed. **EDIT**: Thanks for adding that in!

Answer (score 1):

The `rm` in most Linux distros, and I think Cygwin as well, comes from [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). In my OS, and probably Cygwin, there is a package simply called `coreutils` that contains all of these programs.

Comment: You are correct, thank you! For Cygwin, `setup.exe` needs to be run again.